# Que veut dire « des nuits d'amour à plus finir » ?

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

J'ai appris récemment par cœur la chanson *La vie en rose*, pourtant j'ai du mal à comprendre le sens de la strophe suivante :

> Des nuits d'amour à plus finir
>   Un grand bonheur qui prend sa place
>   Devant elle tous les chagrins s'effacent
>   Heureux, heureux à en mourir.

Particulièrement le vers *Des nuits d'amour à plus finir*, que veut-il dire ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une licence poétique pour *des nuits d'amour à **n'en** plus finir*, c'est à dire:

> Une quantité infinie (illimitée) de nuits d'amour.

On peut aussi le comprendre comme :

> Des nuit d'amour où l'on n'arrête pas (où l'on ne s'endort pas...)

Comment: En tout cas, j'ai du mal à comprendre le sens de l'expression "des nuits d'amour à n'en plus finir". Pouvez-vous l'expliquer?

Comment: - C'est fait ! -